# How to receive gps data faster using KumarRobotics / ublox package?

Tags: gps, ros

Currently I'm using zed-f9p with ublox and ntrip.
below is yaml file.

```
debug: 1

save:
mask: 3103 # Save I/O, Message, INF Message, Nav, Receiver
# Manager, Antenna, and Logging Configuration
device: 4 # Save to EEPROM

device: /dev/ttyACM0
frame_id: gps
rate: 8 # in Hz
nav_rate: 8 # [# of measurement cycles], recommended 1 Hz, may
# be either 5 Hz (Dual constellation) or
# 8 Hz (GPS only)
dynamic_model: automotive # Airborne < 2G, 2D fix not supported (3D only),
# Max Alt: 50km
# Max Horizontal Velocity: 250 m/s,
# Max Vertical Velocity: 100 m/s
fix_mode: auto
enable_ppp: false # Not supported by C94-M8P
dr_limit: 0

uart1:
baudrate: 38400 # zed-f9p specific
in: 32 # RTCM 3
out: 0 # No UART out for rover

gnss:
gps: true
glonass: true
beidou: false
qzss: false

dgnss_mode: 3 # Fixed mode

tmode3: 1

sv_in/min_dur: 0.01
sv_in/acc_lim: 5

inf:
all: true # Whether to display all INF messages in console
Enable u-blox message publishers

publish:
all: true
aid:
hui: false

nav:
posecef: false
```

As I set the rate and nav_rate to 8 and sv_in/min_dur to 0.01, I expected the gps value to be surveyed in at 8Hz.
But the best I could get was 1-2Hz. (I checked it through ros rqt)
So I tried changing values in node.h - kSubscribeRate, kNavSvInfoSubscribeRate, kPollDuration - but the hz in rqt rather went to 0.05Hz and don't come back to 1-2Hz even if I turn the values back and catkinmake.
How can I receive gps data faster?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who still wonders after 7 months:

There is a difference between "rate" and "nav_rate". Kumar Robotics does explain that "rate" equals "measurement rate" in ublox settings. Searching through the F9P manual, "RATE" is split up into two parts.

F9P Interface Description tells us for UBX-CFG-RATE:

> This message allows the user to alter the rate at which navigation
> solutions (and the measurements that they depend on) are generated by
> the receiver.

This configuration is parted into:

> CFG-RATE-MEAS: Nominal time between GNSS measurements

and

> CFG-RATE-NAV: Ratio of number of measurements to number of navigation solutions

To set your parameters correctly you have to set your measurement rate to 8Hz. Further you want your receiver to only use ONE measurement value to produce a navigation solution! This is why your navigation rate should be set to 1.

rate: 8
nav_rate: 1